# Do GitHub Pages repositories have to be public?

Tags: github, github-pages

Do GitHub Pages repositories have to be public, or on a private one is possible?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because a question about Github's pricing policies is not a programming question, as defined in [on-topic](/help/on-topic)

Comment: As I know, you must have a [PRO](https://github.com/pricing) plan to host a private repo

Comment: @NikaNabakhteveli "As I know, you must have a PRO plan to host a private repo" - I do not believe that is correct.  https://github.com/pricing describes the free tier as providing "unlimited public/private repositories".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do GitHub Pages repositories have to be public, or on a private one is
> possible?

It is possible to use GitHub Pages with a private repository.

> GitHub Pages is available in public repositories with GitHub Free and
> GitHub Free for organizations, and in public and private repositories
> with GitHub Pro, GitHub Team, GitHub Enterprise Cloud, and GitHub
> Enterprise Server. For more information, see "GitHub's products."

That is from https://docs.github.com/en/pages/getting-started-with-github-pages/about-github-pages.